# best way to deal with multiple transaction to the database with entity framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

Bit of advice really, i am building an MVC application that takes in feeds for products from multiple sources.  This can run into millions and despite my best advice for the client to split all his feeds into smaller chunks, I know they will probably try and do a thousand at a go.

Now the main problem is that I don't want to loop through every xml record and do an insert.
what i would rather do is queue a stack off inserts and then fly them into the database in one massive transaction.  Very much like a database SQL import of a whole table.

Is this possible?   if so how or what do they call it?

also, if I did want to re-insert repeated products again and again, when nothing has changed, what would be the best practice for this.   could I maybe loop through an already fetched dataset?

I'm not sure what is best to do here, so ask the people,  what is the consensus when it comes to a scenario like this.

thanks

Comment: p.s Entity Framework 4, and .net 4   using MvcScaffolding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the entity framework you will get a single db insert per record you are inserting, there will be no bulk insert (if that is what you were looking for).

However to enclose this in a transaction, you need to do nothing but add your item to the context class.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336792.aspx

This will automatically put in a transaction when you call SaveChanges. All you need to do is ensure you use a single context class and .Add(yourObject) to the context.

So just wait to call SaveChanges until all of the objects have been added to the context.

Comment: are  right i get it, so in theory i am creating an enumerable  object of say products, in the context and then just saving changes on the whole thing?  i was thinking there would be some kind of queue and i would have to add to the queue, but this is cool.  I have though a way around the the other problem by getting existing into an object and then searching that object with linq, it wont query the DB, but will allow for isUpdateAble or isCreatable kind of scenario.